# Exception in configuring Transport Security in Self Hosted Service using NetTcpBinding in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl

This is the configuration on the service side:

```
<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding" contract="a"></endpoint>
<binding name="TcpBinding">
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" clientCredentialType="None">
    </transport>
  </security>
  <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
</binding>

<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
  <serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate  storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="73 b9 d8 98 8d b6 54 bf fb ff 21 0b ac fc 04 19 37 16 71 5f" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

I have created a self signed certificate following this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx

First I created a Certificate that I installed as Root Certificate Authority in Trusted Root Certification Authorities - named 'RootCA'. Then, I created another self signed certificate signed with this 'RootCA' which is issued to 'localhost'.

On the client side, I am using the same configuration elements as on service side. While opening the proxy, I am receiving the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException The X.509
>   certificate CN=localhost chain building failed. The certificate that
>   was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the
>   certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The revocation
>   function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

What else is needed to make this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include this in your client side in endpoint behaviours

    <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="clientBehave">
            <clientCredentials>
               <serviceCertificate>              
<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: if you are using the client certificate also then do the same thing at server side also for service behaviours - serviceCredentials

Comment: revocation mode is used to check if the certificate is still valid, means that the CA has not revoked the certificate from use. There is a certificate revocation list folder in the certificate manager just like the certificate folder when you expand the certificate store. It contains the revocation list of the particular issuer.

Comment: Setting revocationMode to NoCheck will make WCF not to check for the revocation list of the particular certificate.

Comment: This is not correct according to me then, why should this revocationMode of 'NoCheck' should be used if what all I want is to apply Security and this means even if the Certificate is not valid, keep going. I need to find out the reason why this is happening and if the Certificate is not valid then why, when I produced it today only. How can I see this revocation list? In Windows MMC console > Certificates, I can't see an revocation list.

Comment: I have done a +1 for your help though, but I need to find out complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: you can check in folder Intermediate Certificates -> Certificate Revocation List -> select the entry listed and check that. By Default WCF checks the revocation list. Online option can be used but the certificate you just created is a self signed one and hence not issued by a well known certificate authority, hence the check need to be disabled. If you create a self signed certificate by any means then you always need to establish a trust. This option would not be required when you get a certificate from a well defined CA.

Comment: But why, in the first place, the certificate created using `makecert` is being revoked? If I don't get to know this, how will I create another proper self signed certificate?

Comment: If you are setting a security mode to transport in netTcpBinding, then you need to provide a valid server certificate. And to make it acceptable You have to do these stuffs. The error does not always means that your certificate is wrong. It means that WCF cannot establish a trust for that certificate you provided. Thats why it throwed a SECURITYNEGOTIATIONEXCEPTION.

Comment: Its just a security check. And it cannot verify the information, since it was not avialable, hence it throwed an exception. It does not mean that your certificate is revoked.

Comment: How to include a CRL Distribution Point in the Certificate created using makecert.exe?

Comment: I have no Idea about that.